# Xcode 12.3 command codesign failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, command-line, xcode12

I am a student working on an IOS app, and I do not have much programming experience at all. The app I have built works perfectly well on the simulator, but when I tried to load it onto my iPhone, I keep getting the error *Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code*.

I tried to lock/unlock my keychain, but to no avail, so at this point I created another completely blank xcode ios app project, and it still doesn't load onto the device, and I get the same error, which leads me to believe that it isn't a code error.

This issue has really frustrated me, and if anyone could figure out a way to solve it, I'd be very grateful

Comment: First, welcome to Stack Overflow. I think you've analyzed your issue pretty well - creating a blank project and finding the same issue as you app tells me that. So what/where have you tried searching? I see you are using Xcode 12.3... have you tried 12.2? What iOS version is your device using? To me it sounds like you need to work through https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list and make sure everything is set up right - particularly your device identifier.

Comment: Just in case if all is good there? Provide us with more details... I'm sure we can help you out. Happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually resolved my error, and it seemed to be an issue with the keychain, but I had to actually delete my entire login keychain and create a new one, and then the app was loaded onto the device and works properly

Comment: As an aside, something I have found about deleting/re-adding my login keychain on mac, and something that people with this issue should know before they try my solution, is that the solution deletes all of your saved passwords in mac, which can be a problem,